# Part of CSS only works inside html

Tags: html, css

I have an odd question... I am working on 3 different apps, that all use the same css for the most part. 2 work perfectly, and their css files are located in a separate .css document. The third too works properly, but.... Most of the css is in a separate .css document, and thats how it should be, but for some css to work, I actually have to put it in the .html file itself, whereas, this exact same code, works perfectly fine in a separate .css file for the other two apps... I have no idea how this can happen.... If anyone has some possible ideas, let me know :D

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some examples of why it has to be in the html?

Comment: Examples? I assume its because when you have CSS on the page itself, the page CSS overrides the linked CSS. Give us a JSFIDDLE and explain what you want. Your question is impossible to answer at this time.

Comment: If you have to put it in the HTML file (or inline with the element) then it seems likely to be a cascade problem, and some other style rules are overriding the stylesheet.

Comment: Without seeing any code it is really hard to say.  A concrete example of the behaviour would be great.  Keep in mind internal css overrides external css.

Comment: Well I just figured out how to fix it.... I had this particular css file in a css folder, so I just moved it to the main directory and that solved the problem....

Comment: If you managed to solve it, create your own answer. You are allowed and encouraged to do so.  Don't add the solution to your question.

Comment: Sorry, at the time of posting, I was not allowed to answer my own question, because I am a low level on here. I had to wait like 7 hours or some number, i can't remember, but that was why.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess it is because of the cascading nature of CSS (that's what the C stands for).

If I have two stylesheets:

```
reset.css
site.css
```

If reset.css defines a class style:

```
.foo {
    color: red;
}
```

And site.css defines the same class:

```
.foo {
    color: black;
}
```

The color defined in site.css is going to win. I'm not sure if this applies to your scenario, but you might want to look at the development tools in a browser like Chrome / Firefox to see how the styles are being aplied.

Comment: Well I just figured out how to fix it.... I had this particular css file in a css folder, so I just moved it to the main directory and that solved the problem....

Answer (score 0):

Well I just figured out how to fix it.... I had this particular css file in a css folder, so I just moved it to the main directory and that solved the problem (even though it was properly linked to the css folder)....